# class template specialization that compiles in g++ but not Visual C++

Tags: templates, visual-c++, compiler-errors

The following compiles in g++ but not in Visual C++ (Visual Studio Express 2012).  Why?

If I were to call `foo` with a type other than `int` (say, `double`) then I would expect this to break since in that case `B<double>::bbb:aaa` is meaningless.  But if I intend to only call `foo` with type `int` then it should work.  In fact, compilation fails in VC++ even if I don't call `foo` at all!

```
struct A {
    typedef int aaa;
};

template <typename T>
struct B {
    typedef void bbb;
};

template <>
struct B<int> {
    typedef A bbb;
};

template <typename T>
typename B<T>::bbb::aaa // line 16
foo(const T &arg) {     // line 17
    return typename B<T>::bbb::aaa();
}

int main() {
    // Compilation fails with or without the following two lines.
    //int x = 0;
    //foo(x);
}
```

Here is the error message that I get:

```
gcc_vs_vs.cc(16) : error C2510: 'bbb' : left of '::' must be a class/struct/union
gcc_vs_vs.cc(17) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'foo'
gcc_vs_vs.cc(17) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
gcc_vs_vs.cc(17) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before '&'
```

Comment: I believe this is a bug in Visual C++.  I don't see anything wrong with the code.  You can work around the issue by changing the return type to `typename std::common_type<typename B<T>::bbb>::type::aaa`, using `common_type` from the `<type_traits>` header.  Please consider opening a bug on [Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/visualstudio).

Comment: Thanks.  I've filed a bug report: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/777612/class-template-specialization-that-compiles-in-g-but-not-visual-c